# Convert strings from horizontal to vertical

Tags: python

I'd like to know the process of turning the following strings:

```
Hi
Hello
Goodbye
```

To look something like this:

```
    e
    y
  o b
  l d
  l o
i e o
H H G
```

So that the horizontal string is converted to vertical, however starts at a floor, rather than a ceiling.

If anyone could provide some advice to help me get to the right functions or commands then I would appreciate it. I would also like to know how to do this for a list of strings of length x, where x is any number greater than zero. I have experimented with a for x in list(): function, however cannot seem to produce the above output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting challenge to wake up the brain. Try this code:

```
def vertical_print_generator(data, max_length):
    i = max_length
    while i > 0:
        i -= 1
        yield [s[i] for s in data]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_data = ('Hi', 'Hello', 'Goodbye')
    max_length = max(map(len, in_data))
    out_data = ['{:{max_length}}'.format(s, max_length=max_length) for s in in_data]
    for row in vertical_print_generator(out_data, max_length):
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done using Pandas, Python3. It might not suitable for production codebase, but it works.

```
import pandas as pd

input_value = """Hi
Hello
Goodbye
"""

list_of_chars = list(map(lambda x: [*x], input_value.split("\n")))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_chars)
df = df.T[::-1].fillna(value=' ')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(" ".join(row.values))
```

[image: Output]